# How to tell if a number is exactly representable as a 32-bit IEEE float?

Tags: floating-point, binary, bit, cpu-architecture, ieee-754

This is a task from my textbook

Given a hypothetical computer with a word length of 32 bits divided the following way:
1 bit for the sign bit
9 bit biased exponent
23 bit mantissa part

Is 2^-1 + 2^-29 a machine number on this computer? 
How might i go about determining this?

Comment: 32 bits cannot be partitioned into 1 sign bit, 9 exponent bits, and 23 significand bits, because 1+9+23 = 33, not 32. Sometimes the phrasing about the significant is muddled because the mathematical significant may be x+1 bits while the primary encoding of the significand uses x bits (with 1 more bit derived from the exponent encoding). The IEEE-754 standard binary32 format uses 1-8-23, so we would suspect, since 1+9+23=33 suggests an error and the numbers are close to 1-8-23, that the format is 1-8-23. But a textbook might deliberately use a non-standard format. This ought to be clarified…

Comment: … except for the fact that it does not alter the answer; 2^-1 and 2^-29 are too far apart for either 23- or 24-bit significands.

Answer (score 1):

`abs((-1) - (-29))` is larger than the mantissa width so no, that would require too many significant figures (mantissa bits).

If you wrote them out in a non-exponential binary-point notation, like `0.10000...0001`, the gap between the 2 ones would be larger than the mantissa.  (It's like a decimal point, but it's binary place values so we call it a binary point.)

i.e. 2<sup>-29</sup> is less than 1 ulp for 2<sup>-1</sup>.  (ULP = unit in the last place = low bit of the mantissa.)

**Binary floats can represent a fixed number of (binary) "significant figures" equal to the mantissa width, regardless of the exponent.**  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)

---

Note that the stored width of the mantissa is only 23 bits, but there's an implicit leading 1 (for normalized numbers).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

So 1 + 2<sup>-23</sup> is exactly representable.  i.e 1 ulp relative to 1.0 = `2^-23`.  (Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon like C FLT_EPSILON is half a ulp of 1.0, so 2^-24 for binary32 floats.  It's the largest value you can add to `1.0` and still have the result round to `1.0`, i.e. the largest rounding error you can get when adding to `1.0`)

Note that many modern documents use "significand" instead of "mantissa" because it's more mathematically correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Is 2^-1 + 2^-29 a machine number on this computer?
>    How might i go about determining this?

Assuming the hypothetical format is using base 2 (that was not specified), then 2<sup>-1</sup> and 2<sup>-29</sup> are both exactly representable being small powers of 2.  Let us call them `a_1` and `a_29` and assume `a_1 > a_29 > 0`

"1 bit for the sign bit, 
 9 bit biased exponent, 
 23 bit mantissa part" is akin to [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  Should it follow all those rules (including sub-normals), then any subtraction between different values will not result in 0.  This is important for the next step.

Set sum/difference `acc = a_1 +/- a_29` and `acc_1 = acc - a_1`.  If `acc_1 == +/-a_29`, then `acc` was exactly represented, else `acc` was not exactly the sum/difference `a_1 +/- a_29`, just a rounded result.

In the case of 2<sup>-1</sup> and 2<sup>-29</sup>, the difference is not exactly representable as the "23 bit mantissa part" is too narrow to encode exactly a relative difference of 2<sup>-1 - 29</sup>.  We would need about "27-28 bit mantissa part" to do so.

Comment: Interesting point about underflow, but the question is about addition not subtractions.  The `-` signs are in the exponents.  (Well the question isn't *really* about an FP addition, but in this case the inputs are both exactly representable so you can approach it that way.  Assuming binary floats, of course; before my edit the question was tagged with [tag:ieee] and IEEE binary floats are far more common than IEEE decimal floats.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Amended answer to a sum/difference calculation.  Does not change the overall flow much.